# how to replace more than 1 pattern in re

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
a = 'P/2008 A3 (SOHO)'
```

I want to change it to:

```
a = 'P/2008-A3-SOHO'
```

**Attempt to solve the problem:**

Step 1:

```
b = re.sub("\s", "-", a)
print b
```

Output:

```
P/2008-A3-(SOHO)
```

Step 2:

```
c = re.sub("[\(\)]", "", b)
print c
```

Output:

```
P/2008-A3-SOHO
```

I got the output I need, however is there a more effective way to do it? I would like to solve it in 1 step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) not only accepts a string for the second argument, but also accepts a function. The function gets an match object as an argument and the return value of the function is used as a replacement string:

```
>>> re.sub(r"[()\s]", lambda m: '-' if m.group().isspace() else '', a)
'P/2008-A3-SOHO'
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `(`, `)` inside the character class(`[...]`).

Comment: @falsetru the code works, however I would like to understand how the function `lambda` works. Can you provide some details? Thanks :)

Comment: @user3097391, The function receives [a match object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects). A match object has a [`group(..)` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group), which returns a matched string (when called without argument).

Comment: @user3097391, `X if ... else Y` is an conditional expression.

Comment: +1 for lambdas in regex replacements (aka delegates in C#, anonymous functions in JS and Perl and PHP, blocks in Ruby) :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use **capturing groups** to capture specific string from the input.

Regex:

```
^(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*\(([^)]*)\)$
```

Replacement string:

```
\1-\2-\3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uK4sT3/5)

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'P/2008 A3 (SOHO)'
>>> m = re.sub(r'^(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*\(([^)]*)\)$', r'\1-\2-\3', a)
>>> m
'P/2008-A3-SOHO'
```

Answer (score 1):

falsetru has provided a good answer how to do multiple replacements in a single "regex operation".

I would just like to point out that one-liners aren't always better, for reasons of readability as well as efficiency. Two regexes are faster that a single regex with a `lambda` callback, and I'd argue that they are more readable as well:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = "import re; a = 'P/2008 A3 (SOHO) P/2008 A3 (SOHO)'"
>>> stmt1 = """re.sub(r"[()\s]", lambda m: '-' if m.group().isspace() else '', a)"""
>>> stmt1 = """r = re.sub(r"[()\s]", lambda m: '-' if m.group().isspace() else '', a)"""
>>> stmt2 = """r = re.sub("\s", "-", a)
... r = re.sub("[\(\)]", "", r)"""
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=stmt1)
9.311270136909659
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=stmt2)
7.7278099642134315
```

This becomes even more obvious when we compile the regexes (and, for justice, define a function instead of the `lambda`) beforehand:

```
>>> setup = """import re
... a = 'P/2008 A3 (SOHO) P/2008 A3 (SOHO)'
... r1 = re.compile(r"[()\s]")
... r2 = re.compile(r"\s")
... r3 = re.compile(r"[()]")
... def f(m): return '-' if m.group().isspace() else ''
... """
>>> stmt1 = """r = r1.sub(f, a)"""
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=stmt1)
7.351804295542024
>>> stmt2 = """r = r2.sub("-", a)
... r = r3.sub("", r)"""
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=stmt2)
4.5631406412521756
```